# get corresponding column of a dataframe by looking at columns of another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, slice

I have two dataframes for groundtruth and predicted trajectories and one dataframe for matching between the groundtruth and predicted trajectories at each frame.
I have dataframe of the groundtruth tracks and predicted tracks as follows:

```
df_pred_batch = 
             CENTER_X  CENTER_Y  LENGTH  SPEED  ACCELERATION  HEADING
FrameId HId                                                           
0       0   -1.870000     -0.41    1.51  1.280         1.670     0.39
1       0   -1.730000     -0.36    1.51  1.440         1.660     0.40
2       0   -1.180000     -1.57    2.05  2.220         0.390     0.61
0       1   -1.540000     -1.83    2.05  2.140         0.390     0.61
1       1   -1.370000     -1.70    2.05  2.180         0.390     0.61
2       1   -1.590000     -0.29    1.51  1.610         1.630     0.41
1       2   -1.910000     -1.12    1.04  0.870         1.440     0.30
2       2   -1.810000     -1.09    1.04  1.010         1.440     0.27
0       3   17.190001     -3.15    1.80  2.178        -0.028     3.36
1       3   15.000000     -3.60    1.80  2.170        -0.020     3.38
df_gt_batch = 
            CENTER_X  CENTER_Y  LENGTH  SPEED  ACCELERATION  HEADING
FrameId OId                                                          
1       0      -1.91     -1.12   1.040   0.87          1.44     0.30
2       0      -1.81     -1.09   1.040   1.01          1.44     0.27
0       1      -1.87     -0.41   1.510   1.28          1.67     0.39
1       1      -1.73     -0.36   1.510   1.44          1.66     0.40
2       1      -1.59     -0.29   1.510   1.61          1.63     0.41
0       2      -1.54     -1.83   2.056   2.14          0.39     0.61
1       2      -1.37     -1.70   2.050   2.18          0.39     0.61
2       2      -1.18     -1.57   2.050   2.22          0.39     0.61
0       3       1.71     -0.31   1.800   2.17         -0.02     3.36
1       3       1.50     -0.36   1.800   2.17         -0.02     3.38
2       3       1.29     -0.41   1.800   2.17         -0.01     3.40
```

Also, I know their matching at each timestamp:

```
matched_gt_pred = 
   FrameId   Type  OId  HId
0        0  MATCH  1.0  0.0
1        0  MATCH  2.0  1.0
4        1  MATCH  1.0  0.0
5        1  MATCH  2.0  1.0
6        1  MATCH  0.0  2.0
9        2  MATCH  0.0  2.0
```

I would like to look at each row of matched_gt_pred and get the corresponding CENTER_X from df_pred_batch and df_gt_batch and calculate the error.
For instance looking at the first row of the `matched_gt_pred` I know at `FrameId == 0` and `OId == 1` and `HId == 0` are matched.
I should get the `Center_X` from `gt_center_x = df_gt_batch["FrameId==0" and "OId == 1"].CENTER_X and pred_center_x = df_pred_batch["FrameId==0" and "HId == 0"].CENTER_X`
And compute `error = abs(gt_center_x - pred_center_x)`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, I would reshape your df_gt_batch and df_pred_batch and use lookup:

```
gt_x = df_gt_batch['Center_X'].unstack().lookup(match_gt_pred['FrameId'], match_gt_pred['OId']) 
pred_x = df_pred_batch['Center_X'].unstack().lookup(match_gt_pred['FrameId'], match_gt_pred['HId'])
match_gt_pred['X Error'] = np.abs(gt_x - pred_x)
```

Output:

```
   FrameId   Type  OId  HId  X Error
0        0  MATCH  1.0  0.0      0.0
1        0  MATCH  2.0  1.0      0.0
4        1  MATCH  1.0  0.0      0.0
5        1  MATCH  2.0  1.0      0.0
6        1  MATCH  0.0  2.0      0.0
9        2  MATCH  0.0  2.0      0.0
```

Another option is to use `reindex` with `pd.MultiIndex`:

```
match_gt_pred['X Error'] = (df_pred_batch.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([match_gt_pred['FrameId'], match_gt_pred['HId']]))['Center_X'].to_numpy() - 
df_gt_batch.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([match_gt_pred['FrameId'], match_gt_pred['OId']]))['Center_X'].to_numpy())
```

Comment: That seems very complicated. Both are index tables and the index is in the `matched_gt_pred`. I would advise using the `df.query` method.

Comment: @Wli  Would you post your `df.query` method.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your OId and HId are integers

```
def get_error(row):
    OId = row['OId']
    HId = row['HId']
    FId = row['FrameId']

    gt_x = df_gt_batch.query('FrameID == @FId and FrameID == @OId')
    pred_x = df_pred_batch.query('FrameID == @FId and HId == @HId')
    return np.abs(gt_x - pred_x)

match_gt_pred['X Error'] = match_gt_pred.apply(get_error, axis=1)
```

using `apply` on each row (`axis = 1`), you're sure to get it in the right order.

Note that rather than using the `query` method, you could directly call your index with call like that: `gt_x = df_gt_batch.loc[(FId,OId)]` (I didn't test that). See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index

Comment: This is a really slow method.  You are iterating row by row. Using `apply` with `axis=1` is not advisable.

Comment: good to know, I would think it would be efficient enough as the results are independent from each other. I guess using `raw=True` could make it more efficient, must be tested... Is `lookup` much faster then?